# Removing certain newlines from a file with Perl

Tags: perl, shell

I'm using the following shell script to cleanse a file. The file contains data records from a database but seeing as some have new lines in the fields it's caused some records to spread over two lines which then causes issues when loading. The text is enclosed with "" and delimited by commas so I use the following shell script to remove the new lines which works fine but takes around 8 minutes on a 2mil record file, from what I understand Perl will be much quicker.

I have absolutely no understanding of Perl, could someone translate/explain the following in Perl?

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file=$1
gawk -v RS='"' 'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\n/, "") } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }' $input_file > $input_file"_temp"
mv $input_file"_temp" $input_file
```

**Edit:** I can't give exact data but the issue would be similar to this (Records delimited by newline):

```
"001", "Dave Surname", "1 High Street"
"002", "John Surname", "2 High
Street"
"003", "Bill Surname", "3 High Street"
"004", "James 
Surname", "4 High Street"
```

Judging by the above someone's put a new line in the address field so this should become:

```
"001", "Dave Surname", "1 High Street"
"002", "John Surname", "2 High Street"
"003", "Bill Surname", "3 High Street"
"004", "James Surname", "4 High Street"
```

Comment: Can you post say 3-5 lines of the input for testing? Make sure at least one has the newline, so we're working with the exact data sample you are.

Comment: Since your record separator is always the same, I think you can possibly get away with using `print $0 RS` - either way, using `print` instead of `printf` will probably speed things up. I'm not sure that porting to Perl is going to get you much of a performance gain for free (although it would be interesting to see the effect).

Comment: @stevieb Unfortunately I'm unable to post any of the data as it's sensitive data which is a little inconvenient. I'll see if I'm able to re-create an example.

Comment: @TomFenech You say using print will generally be faster than printf, I'll try it out. But from what I've read Perl is generally a lot faster for file manipulation than shell?

Comment: @MattDamon a sanitized sample will do. All that needs to be consistent with the original data are the line and record separators.

Comment: Put it this way - we don't want to see your data, but we do want something we can use to test our scripts to check they're 'doing it right'. Mocking up two examples of lines and how they should (or shouldn't) be transformed is fine.

Comment: @Matt you're currently using `gawk` to manipulate the data, which is a tool designed with that purpose in mind. I wouldn't expect it to be significantly faster or slower than perl. If you were using a `while read` loop in the shell, then that is usually a lot slower (and possibly the kind of thing that you have read about).

Comment: Added a very simple example of what the data is structured like. Hopefully enough to explain/test what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need some sample data to be sure. I would guess that what is going on here is you're trying to parse a CSV file, and getting caught by line feeds in your records.

This is one reason why a line/regex based approach to CSV is a bad idea, generally. Thankfully, there is a nice easy solution in perl - the [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.33/lib/Text/CSV.pm) module.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;
my ( $filename ) = @ARGV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1, eol => $/ } );

open( my $input, "<", $filename ) or die $!;

while ( my $row = $csv->getline($input) ) {
    foreach my $element (@$row) {
        $element =~ s/\n/ /g;
    }
    $csv->print( \*STDOUT, $row );
}
close($input);
```

This will iterate each line in a filename specified on command line -  and delete any line feeds that are embedded in fields, whilst preserving those outside the fields.

Comment: No one on my team has knowledge of Perl all I know is we have v5.8.8 installed. If I put this script in a test.pl file and run perl test.pl filename.csv I get this error: Can't locate Text/CSV.pm in @INC

Comment: `5.8.8` is an old version of perl. (2008 was a while ago!) You should, however, be able to install the module with `cpan Text::CSV`  I wouldn't suggest using a workaround, because that will also trip up on the new lines.

Comment: We do seem to have a passion for old versions, as no one uses it we've never really felt the need to update. It's also quite a lot of effort trying to get a version updated with the guys who manage the servers. I'll get it on a virtual machine and test it, if it's much quicker I'll have a reason! So I just need to do that cpan and run as I was?

Comment: You may also find the package is available to your version of Unix.

Comment: It doesn't look like I'm able to install the module over our network. Is there any other implementation or are other ways not worth doing over shell?

Comment: Have a look at the package list available on your host. It may be it's available. Otherwise - I'm afraid ... what you've got is probably the best that's available.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81253/discussion-between-matt-damon-and-sobrique).

Answer (score -1):

This will do as you ask. It appends each line to the variable `$r` and, if the result contains an even number of double quotes, it prints `$r` and empties it

```
perl -i -lne'unless (($r .= $_) =~ tr/"// % 2) { print $c; $r = ""}' $input_file
```